# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, email image from app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I am trying to attach an image rendered from UIGraphicsBeginImageContext. As a test, I am adding the image to the photo album as well. It all works perfectly on the simulator, but on the device the correct image get added to the photo album, but will not display in the email attachment correctly. I think it is because it is a big image, and it takes some time on an iPhone 3gs. Which means I have to check if it is done rendering image. Is there a way to to that? Here is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backGround.layer.frame.size);
[backGround.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[mailer addAttachmentData:imgData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myfilename"];
```

I am wondering, maybe it is not completely finished with the image, and it still has corrupted data when I am making a PNG Representation of it. Can I somehow check if the UIImage is 'done' ?

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing the completion method and check it. One example is,

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);

- (void)image:(UIImage *) image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo {
        NSLog(@"SAVE IMAGE COMPLETE");
        if(error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR SAVING:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }
```

Based on the error message you can debug for the error message. Check [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum) for more details.

Comment: Actually, I dont want to save to library, I was just doing so to check if image were corrupted. But it looked good in the photoalbum..

Comment: But can you check what is the error message displayed while saving to photo album in device? Probably that should give you the complete picture.

Comment: That is true. I get no errors, it also saves the image correctly to the photo album. The problem is, I think the image is not finished when I try to attach it to the e-mail. Is there a way to check if the image is finished rendering?